# Incompatible shape with the expected and input shapes in AI model creation

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I'm pretty new to this AI model creation and I'm trying to create a activity recognition model using heatmaps using this reference [Human activity recognition model](https://bleedai.com/human-activity-recognition-using-tensorflow-cnn-lstm/)

- In the above link they're doing activity recognition by providing some video feed, the videos have been sliced into frames and training the model here in reference link.
- But in my case I'm providing the sliced frames(images) directly for the training.
  **The problem is that when I'm providing my dataset for AI model creation, the input is not matching with expected input**.

I'm getting this error
***ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 4, 8, 8, 3), found shape=(4, 8, 8, 3)***
Here is my code

```
seed_constant = 27
np.random.seed(seed_constant)
random.seed(seed_constant)
tf.random.set_seed(seed_constant)

CLASSES_LIST = ["Forward", "Backward"]
SEQUENCE_LENGTH = 4
IMAGE_HEIGHT = 8
IMAGE_WIDTH = 8
DATASET_DIR = r"D:\ppl_count.tar (1)\ppl_count\ppl_count\datasets\ir\dataset_test"
Input = (IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT)


def create_dataset():
"""
This function will extract the data of the selected classes and create the required dataset.
Returns:
    features:          A list containing the extracted frames of the videos.
    labels:            A list containing the indexes of the classes associated with the videos.
    video_files_paths: A list containing the paths of the videos in the disk.
"""
images_dire = r"D:\ppl_count.tar (1)\ppl_count\ppl_count\datasets\ir\test_sample"

dataset_files = create_dataset_files(images_dir=images_dire, datasets_dir=DATASET_DIR,
                                     split_size=100,
                                     num_threads=1,
                                     resize=Input, normalize=True)

return dataset_files


create_dataset()
data1 = numpy.load(r"D:\ppl_count.tar 
(1)\ppl_count\ppl_count\datasets\ir\dataset_test\dataset0.npz",
               allow_pickle=True)
features_ = data1.f.data

labels_ = data1.f.labels

one_hot_encoded_labels = to_categorical(labels_)

# splits data into train and test sets
features_train, features_test, labels_train, labels_test = train_test_split(features_, 
                                                                one_hot_encoded_labels,
                                                                        test_size=0.25, 
                                                                    shuffle=True,
                                                            random_state=seed_constant)
 print("dataset_creation_success")


def create_convlstm_model():
"""
This function will construct the required convlstm model.
Returns:
    model: It is the required constructed convlstm model.
"""

# We will use a Sequential model for model construction
model = Sequential()

# Define the Model Architecture.
# #######################################################################################################################

model.add(ConvLSTM2D(filters=4, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='tanh', data_format="channels_last",
                     recurrent_dropout=0.2, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(SEQUENCE_LENGTH,
                                                                                IMAGE_HEIGHT, IMAGE_WIDTH, 3)))

model.add(MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(1, 2, 2), strides=(1, 1, 1), padding='same', data_format='channels_last'))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dropout(0.2)))
print(f'1_works')
model.add(ConvLSTM2D(filters=8, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='tanh', data_format="channels_last",
                     recurrent_dropout=0.2, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(SEQUENCE_LENGTH,
                                                                                IMAGE_HEIGHT, IMAGE_WIDTH, 3)))

model.add(MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(1, 2, 2), strides=(1, 1, 1), padding='same', data_format='channels_last'))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dropout(0.2)))
print(f'2_works')
model.add(ConvLSTM2D(filters=14, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='tanh', data_format="channels_last",
                     recurrent_dropout=0.2, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(SEQUENCE_LENGTH,
                                                                                IMAGE_HEIGHT, IMAGE_WIDTH, 3)))

model.add(MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(1, 2, 2), strides=(1, 1, 1), padding='same', data_format='channels_last'))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dropout(0.2)))
print(f'3_works')
model.add(ConvLSTM2D(filters=16, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='tanh', padding='same', data_format="channels_last",
                     recurrent_dropout=0.2, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(SEQUENCE_LENGTH,
                                                                                IMAGE_HEIGHT, IMAGE_WIDTH, 3)))

model.add(MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(1, 2, 2), strides=(1, 1, 1), padding='same', data_format='channels_last'))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dropout(0.2)))

model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(len(CLASSES_LIST), activation="softmax"))
# #######################################################################################################################

# Display the models summary.
model.summary()

# Return the constructed convlstm model.
return model


convlstm_model = create_convlstm_model()

# Display the success message.
print("Model Created Successfully!")

early_stopping_callback = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=10, mode='min', 
restore_best_weights=True)

# Compile the model and specify loss function, optimizer and metrics values to the model
convlstm_model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='Adam', metrics= 
["accuracy"])

# Start training the model.
convlstm_model_training_history = convlstm_model.fit(x=features_train, y=labels_train, 
epochs=50, batch_size=4,
                                                 shuffle=True, validation_split=0.2,
                                                 callbacks=[early_stopping_callback])
```

**please do ignore some indentations as it's very difficult to post with indentations and provide any solution/reference where I can get answer from. **

Comment: I would think that SEQUENCE_LENGTH = 4 is your batch_size, and therefore in the first convlayers inputshape you only need to define: input_shape=(IMAGE_HEIGHT, IMAGE_WIDTH, 3)

Comment: Thanks @FranciskaRajki for reply, I tried the way you mentioned but getting improper dimension error 'ValueError: Input 0 of layer "conv_lstm2d" is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=5, found ndim=4. Full shape received: (None, 8, 8, 3)'

Answer (score 0):

`tf.keras.layers.ConvLSTM2D` expects input of shape 5D but you are giving 4D input.

I could reproduce your issue

```
import tensorflow as tf
SEQUENCE_LENGTH = 4
IMAGE_HEIGHT = 8
IMAGE_WIDTH = 8
input_shape = (SEQUENCE_LENGTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT, IMAGE_WIDTH,3)
x = tf.random.normal(input_shape)
y = tf.keras.layers.ConvLSTM2D(filters=4, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='tanh', data_format="channels_last",
                     recurrent_dropout=0.2, return_sequences=True, input_shape=input_shape)(x)
print(y.shape)
```

**Output**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-6a18c66320ed> in <module>()
      5 x = tf.random.normal(input_shape)
      6 y = tf.keras.layers.ConvLSTM2D(filters=4, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='tanh', data_format="channels_last",
----> 7                      recurrent_dropout=0.2, return_sequences=True, input_shape=input_shape)(x)
      8 print(y.shape)

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/input_spec.py in assert_input_compatibility(input_spec, inputs, layer_name)
    212       ndim = shape.rank
    213       if ndim != spec.ndim:
--> 214         raise ValueError(f'Input {input_index} of layer "{layer_name}" '
    215                          'is incompatible with the layer: '
    216                          f'expected ndim={spec.ndim}, found ndim={ndim}. '

ValueError: Input 0 of layer "conv_lstm2d_4" is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=5, found ndim=4. Full shape received: (4, 8, 8, 3)
```

**Working sample code**

```
import tensorflow as tf
SEQUENCE_LENGTH = 4
IMAGE_HEIGHT = 8
IMAGE_WIDTH = 8
input_shape = (16,SEQUENCE_LENGTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT, IMAGE_WIDTH,3)
x = tf.random.normal(input_shape)
y = tf.keras.layers.ConvLSTM2D(filters=4, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='tanh', data_format="channels_last",
                     recurrent_dropout=0.2, return_sequences=True, input_shape=input_shape)(x)
print(y.shape)
```

**Output**

```
(16, 4, 6, 6, 4)
```